# dynamically creating variables based on the condition, SAS

Tags: loops, sas

My problem is following:

I have a dataset with two columns

```
number_of_years payment
4               100
5               123
2               52
```

and I would like to create new variable (or set of variables and then to sum them) and add value based on the value in the column number_of_years.

New variable should get following value:

```
number_of_years payment new_variable
4               100     100*1.01**4 + 100*1.01**3 + 100*1.01**2 + 100*1.01**1
5               123     123*1.01**5 + 123*1.01**4 + 123*1.01**3 + 123*1.01**2 + 123*1.01*1 
2               52      52*1.01**2 + 52*1.01**1   
e.t.c.
```

My original idea was to put a value from the column number_of_years into macro variable, loop with its value creating additional columns and then sum it, but it does not work.

```
data uprava;
 set work.data_diskontace;

%let value1=number_of_years;

%macro spocti(n);
%do i=1 %to &n; 
new_variable&i = payment*1.01**&i;
%end;
%mend doit;
%spocti(value1);

run;
```

Thank you for any suggestion which way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use regular loops instead of macro loops, because number of iteration is dynamic depends on `number_of_years` variable.

```
data uprava;
    set work.data_diskontace;

    new_variable = 0;
    do i = 1 to number_of_years;
         new_variable = new_variable + payment*1.01**i;
    end;
run;
```

Comment: thank you, i´ve found out solution using arrays too.

Comment: @jirijansa my solution is a lot simpler! no need for loops, arrays etc... just basic math

Answer (score 2):

No need for macros this is a geometric series that converge to

[image]

Simplest solution is:

```
data have;
input years payment;
cards;
4 100
5 123
2 52
;
run;

data want;
set have;
new_variable = (1.01*(1-1.01**years)/(1-1.01))*payment;
run;
```